# Reading from a text file; how do I determine how many fields each line holds?

Tags: c#, file, deserialization

So, I'm trying to read from a text file and store each line into an object, and then each individual value (split by ',') into a list. Here's a quick example:

**Text file dummy information:**
1, Book One, 22, 5
2, Book Two, 10, 3
3, Book Three, 5, 15

But if for example, line 2 had the following:
**Text file dummy information:**
1, Book One, 22, 5
2, Book Two, 10, 3, 22.0, 5
3, Book Three, 5, 15

Comment: The whole point of design patterns is to explain code structure to other developers. Additionally, where in the world do you even mention design patterns here? I think you may need to read up on them.

Comment: You wouldn't like it to count the , for each line, would you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, It seems that checking the length of the **current** holdingArray should tell you which line has more -or less- values than expected. After all, you are splitting the lines by the comma character.

Comment: Yes, it seems I'll have to use a few IF statements to see if that value is present, and if it is present, store that particular value into a variable. I just thought there would be a better way to do this that's all.

Comment: @Xiy there *is* an alternative, though it may not be acceptable in your situation: require your input files to have the same number of values in every row, and reject the file if it is not valid.